# Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operand of type 'bool' and 'int'

Tags: c#, .net

I have an if elseif statement to check marks and grade the marks according to the condition.

```
int marks;
string grade;

if (marks>=80 && marks!>100)
{
  grade = "A1";
}
else if (marks>=70 && marks!>79)
{
  grade = "A2";
}
```

and so on.....

however, when i compile it i got

> Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operand of type 'bool' and 'int'

help me fix it.thanks in advance.

Comment: nice thinking that you can just stitch signs to make an operator.

Comment: @Dani: It makes more sense than you'd think.  After all, `<=` is "less than or equal", and `!=` means "not equal".  `!>` seems a natural translation of "not greater than".  Just happens that it's not valid C#.

Comment: @cHao: what I was trying to say that language is a set of rules, not what you consider "natural translation"

Comment: @Dani: the "natural translation" comes from taking known rules and extrapolating.  The thought process is sound -- it's just not always correct if the language isn't internally consistent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other answers have made it known that the main problem is that `!>` isn't an operator.

I'd like to suggest that since you're testing whether `marks` lies within particular ranges that you take an additional further step to format your conditional expressions to use the following pattern:

```
if (80 <= marks && marks <= 100)
{
  grade = "A1";
}
else if (70 <= marks && marks <= 79)
{
  grade = "A2";
}
```

It's a simple and maybe subtle change, but I think it makes the range check intent much more clear.

Answer (score 13):

That is not a real operator:

```
!>
```

Not Greater Than would be `<=`   (Less Than or Equal To)

EDIT: What you are trying to say could actually also be expressed using the ! operator.  But it would be

```
!(marks > 100 )
```

Comment: cant believe how silly i am. thanks you very much.that works.

Answer (score 4):

you have used the wrong operator,

it must be.

```
int marks;
string grade;

if (marks>=80 && marks<=100)
{
  grade = "A1";
}
elseif (marks>=70 && marks<=79)
{
  grade = "A2";
}
```

Also you can do is

```
int marks;
string grade;

if (marks>=80 && !(marks>100))
{
  grade = "A1";
}
elseif (marks>=70 && !(marks>79))
{
  grade = "A2";
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Eppiey, operator < or > cant be used with not, only = can  be used with !=.

Answer (score 1):

```
int marks;
string grade;

if ((marks>=80) && !(marks > 100))
{
grade = "A1";
}
else if ((marks>=70) && !(marks > 79))
{
grade = "A2";
}
```